# How to fix 'NoMethodError' error in views Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got a problem NoMethodError in Cards#card_list.

I has a problem, it says problem in 3 line:

```
.placeholder2.container.visible.card_list.row
- items.each_with_index do |cards, i|
.col-md.card-column{data: {color: cards[4].first.color, type: cards[4].first.card_class}}
  %h4
    %span{class: "icon-#{i == 4 ? ico_item : icon}"}
      = entities[i]
```

In log file it say:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass):
```

My full code in this template:

```
.placeholder2.container.visible.card_list.row
- items.each_with_index do |cards, i|
.col-md.card-column{data: {color: cards[1].first.color, type: cards[1].first.card_class}}
  %h4
    %span{class: "icon-#{i == 4 ? ico_item : icon}"}
      = entities[i]
  - cards[1].each do |card|
    .col-md-12.card_line.tooltip-card{style: "padding:0px;margin:0;", data: {id: card.id, color: card.color, type: card.card_class, rarity: card.rarity, set: card.card_set, eng_title: card.eng_title&.downcase || '', title: card.title&.downcase}}
      = link_to card, class: "#{color_class(card.color)}-card-tooltip card-tooltip", target: '_blank' do
        %div.cards_gr{class: "bg1_#{color_class(card.color)}", style: "border-left: 4px solid #{rarity_color(card.rarity)};"}
          %div{:style => "padding-right: 10px;float:left;"}
            - if card.card_class == 1
              = image_tag card.hero_icon.url(:small), width: '20px', height: '20px', style: "margin-top:-4px;"
            - elsif card.card_class == 3
              %span{:style => "font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;"}= card.item_gold
            - else
              %span{:style => "font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;"}= card.manacost
          = card.title
```

How i can fix it?

Comment: Looks like `cards` doesn't contain 5 elements. Remember that array indexes start at 0 so `cards[4]` is referring to the 5th element in the array. This will be `nil` if the array doesn't contain that many elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that cards[4] is nil, you have to check for that and maybe put some defaults like this:

```
items.each_with_index do |cards, i|
  if cards[4]
    data = { color: cards[4].first.color,type: cards[4].first.card_class }
  else
    data = { color: 'default', type: 'default' }
  end

  .col-md.card-column{data: data}

end
```

Comment: Using defaults can be a good idea, but this isn't quite right. Elements from a `Hash` as used for the default can't be accessed using dot notation such as `.card_class`, `.color` etc.

Comment: that could be another solution

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you have `cards[4]` and in the second `cards[1]`. Not sure if that discrepancy is on purpose. You are getting a `NoMethodError` because there are not 5 elements in the cards array.  `cards[4]` is returning `nil`.